# Fix X and Y axis widths, JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

How can I achieve fixed Axis width using JavaFx line graph.

```
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Axis extends Application
{

    private Timeline animation;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        final NumberAxis x = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis y = new NumberAxis();
        x.setAutoRanging(false);
        y.setAutoRanging(false);

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(x, y);
        // final Series series = new LineChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        //
        // series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 23));
        // series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(35, 14));
        // series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(43, 15));
        // series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(60, 24));
        // series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 34));
        //
        // lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.setPrefHeight(10);
        lineChart.setPrefWidth(10);
        lineChart.setMinHeight(10);
        lineChart.setMinWidth(10);
        lineChart.setMaxHeight(10);
        lineChart.setMaxWidth(10);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop()
    {
        animation.pause();
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like the grid (sample marked in red) not to scale when I resize the window. Currently the grid resizes when the window is resized as shown below

[image]

I am not able to achieve what I need using the minWidth and maxWidth API's

Comment: Is your question "How to resize the graph while maintaining aspect ratio?" or is it "How to prevent any resizing of the graph?"

Comment: How to prevent any resizing of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preventing resizing of a Graph**

You can prevent the graph resizing by setting it's preferred, min and max sizes:

```
lineChart.setMinSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
lineChart.setPrefSize(800, 600);
lineChart.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

The only exception to this is when the chart is the root of the scene, in which case you should wrap the chart in a Pane or Group to prevent it being resized to fit the scene (because of a layout quirk in the JavaFX 8 rendering logic).

Also note, wrapping any resizable node a Group will size the node (excluding transforms and effects) to it's preferred dimensions and never change them.

Unfortunately, setting the preferred size of the graph isn't exactly the same as setting the preferred sizes of the graph's axes directly, as it makes the entire chart that size, not a specific axis line, which is probably what you are looking for with your question.

**Preventing resizing of a Graph Axis**

*I don't know how to do this.*

You might think you could do the following:

```
xAxis.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
xAxis.setPrefWidth(800);
xAxis.setMaxWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

But this doesn't work in Java 8 when the axis is embedded inside a chart.  This is because the XYChart layout routine ignores the preferred, min and max sizes of it's axes when it lays out the chart contents.

This is perhaps a bug, so you might want to log it as such at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com.

Comment: as per your suggestion I wrapped the chart in a BorderPane() and set the lineChart's MinSize, PrefSize and MaxSize and it doesn't scale the chart any more.

public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
 {
  final NumberAxis x = new NumberAxis();
  ...
  lineChart.setMinSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
  lineChart.setPrefSize(800, 800);
  lineChart.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

  final BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
  border.setTop(lineChart);

  final Scene scene = new Scene(border);
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();
 }